# How clever is a compiler (e.g. g++) at SSE optimisation (line re-ordering, operation collation)

Tags: g++, compiler-optimization, sse

Without getting into a discussion about premature optimisation, I have a few questions about how well g++ or other compilers handle SSE optimisation, when the relevant compiler flags are selected:

1. Do multiple lines of code get re-ordered in order for SSE instructions to be performed on bunches of lines? e.g.

   ```
   a[0] = a1+a2+a3;
   x[0] = a1*a1;
   a[1] = b1+b2+b3;
   x[1] = b1*b1;
   a[2] = c1+c2+c3;
   x[2] = c1*c1;
   ```

   where the compiler could reorder  these lines into two sets of SSE instructions?
2. Does the compiler realise when to take similar sets of operations, that are not in arrays and combine them into SSE instructions? e.g.

   ```
   a = a1+a2+a3;
   b = b1+b2+b3;
   c = c1+c2+c3;
   ```
3. Does the compiler optimise instructions in a for loop for SSE optimisation? e.g.

   ```
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
       x[i] = x[i]*k;
       a[i] = a[i]*c;
   }
   ```

Will a compiler combine 1, 2 and 3 when trying to optimise?

Would be interesting to hear peoples thoughts on this for various SSE optimising compilers.

edit: I'm mostly asking about g++, but other "mainstream" compilers are of interest. I'm also predominantly talking about floating point operations.

Comment: Are you just talking about strictly vertical operations on float/double ? Because integer, fixed point, etc, and operations requiring widening/narrowing or permutations are a whole other story...

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it is currently too broad. "A compiler" is virtually limitless. If you could narrow this down to a *specific* compiler, then it would become much more answerable. You've tagged it [g++]; does that imply you want to focus only on GCC?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, compilers made a real improvement for vectorization three years ago.  Presently, all of your examples will be vectorized efficiently. Moreover, if you have the chance to use Intel's compiler, you will get a huge speed-up, and its reporting mode will give you additional information about the optimizations it applied.

In my day-to-day life, I've seen that you can have the craziest code, but for the computation part, you should help the compiler and use a C approach where you extract your pointer and do your loop:

```
float * pa = whatever;      // data must be contigious
float * pb = whatever;

for (int i=0; i <n; ++i)
{
     pa[I] = pa[i]*pb[i];   // example
}
```

Now we also have [OpenMP 4.5, which provides directives for vectorization](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/03/22/what-is-new-in-openmp-4-5-3/). This will only be 10% slower than a hand-written solution. Therefore, I do not recommend today to move to intrinsics, except in very specific cases where `#pragma` will not work.

Comment: Why do you mention that Intel's compiler will give you a speed up? Are you implying it will speed things up more than g++? If so why?

Comment: Compiler is a very hard science. You will get 40% more than GCC. For the following reason: 1) special math function do not break vectorization (experience, cos, ...) because Intel provides implementation, GCC not. 2) Intel compiler manages well branching GCC less. 3) Intel is dedicated to Intel platform. GCC is Multiplatform which is good and bad. 4) indirect are much managed than GCC (a[b[I]]) and outline loop vectorization can work, more and less never for GCC.